ERC20 approve for uniswap swap router failing on mainnet (but working on sepolia)
I have this contract
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract my_contract {
   
    address private constant SWAP_ROUTER = 0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564;
    address private constant token0 = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2; // WETH
    address private constant token1 = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7; // USDT
    
    address private immutable _owner;
    
    constructor() {
        _owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    fallback() external payable {
        revert("Not accepted");
    }

    receive() external payable {
        revert("Not accepted");
    }  

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == _owner, "NOT_AUTHORIZED");
        _;
    }    
    
    function approve(uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20(token0).approve(SWAP_ROUTER, amount0);
        IERC20(token1).approve(SWAP_ROUTER, amount1);
    }        
      
    // ...
 }

When I call approve for my contract deployed on mainnet (e.g. with amount0 and amount1 being ethers.BigNumber.from(2).pow(256).sub(1)), it gives "FAIL". See for instance, https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0xb3f1fadef5de0927e7c26e33fe77943a49cc44c69b08dc9c3a2e51257a94c6ed?trace=0.
Curiously, deploying exact same contract on sepolia, the same call to approve works fine.
Really don't know what to do - what am I missing here?
